# Problem with simple rigging

Tags: rigging

After posing my metarig, i had strange rig object, I dont understand absolutely why this happens:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you should be able to reduce the bone size in Edit mode

Comment: the "strange object" in screenshot 1 is the root of the generated rig. It should be right under your model. Have you applied *Scale*, and *Location* to your model and the metarig?